# Java - KeyBinding in a CardLayout

Tags: java, swing, key-bindings

I have a java program and I used KeyBinding for my key events.I am also using a CardLayout for my JFrame.

The problem is that the KeyBindings don't work unless I click on a different window and go back to my JFrame. For example, I use my application and use Google Chrome and go back to my JFrame. Then the KeyBinding works.

Here is my code:

```
package display.game;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;

public class Game extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    // ------VARIABLES-----//
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private int _W = 1000;

    private ImageIcon blue_paddle_img = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(
            "res/PNG Files/paddle_blue.png"));
    private Blue_Paddle blue_paddle = new Blue_Paddle(blue_paddle_img);

    private ImageIcon red_paddle_img = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(
            "res/PNG Files/paddle_red.png"));
    private Red_Paddle red_paddle = new Red_Paddle(red_paddle_img);

    public Game() {
        setLayout(null);
        addComponents();
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        setFocusable(true);

        //KEYBINDING
        setInputMap(WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT, getInputMap());
        KeyStroke key = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, 0);
        getInputMap().put(key, "pressed");
        getActionMap().put("pressed", new AbstractAction() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                blue_paddle.move(0,5);
                addComponents();

            }

        });

    }

    public void addComponents() {
        blue_paddle.move(0, 0);
        add(blue_paddle);

        red_paddle.move(0, 0);
        add(red_paddle);
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you expect when your key binding should work? When you are in chrome?

Comment: The problem is, the applet may not think it has focus.  You could try using `requestFocusInWindow` when you switch cards

Comment: @htz No I said that I go back to my JFrame and then I press the button in my key binding

Comment: ah, my fault. Try MadProgrammers suggestion

Comment: getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN), "pressed");